# Calculated Field Updating Every Row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, default-value, computed-column

I added a calculated field to my table, and only want to update `NULL` rows (or "new" rows).  Something is going awry, and every row in my table is being updated with the current `DateTime` when 1 row is inserted.  This is the `Create Table` syntax, what must I do so that only the "new" rows are updated with the current `DateTime`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SE](
[dbID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[uqID] [varchar](31) NOT NULL,
[POD] [varchar](255) NULL,
[EC] [varchar](255) NULL,
[S1] [varchar](35) NULL,
[S2] [varchar](35) NULL,
[S3] [varchar](35) NULL,
[S4] [varchar](35) NULL,
[S5] [varchar](35) NULL,
[S6] [varchar](35) NULL,
[S7] [varchar](35) NULL,
[PSD] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DS] [datetime] NULL,
[CN] [varchar](max) NULL,
[autodate]  AS (getdate()),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[dbID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want a calculated column, instead just use a datetime (non-nullable) column, with a default constraint using getdate().

The syntax for the column in the table definition SQL is as follows:

```
[autodate] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE())
```

A [Computed Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300.aspx) in SQL Server is calculated when it is queried (unless it is PERSISTED, then it has a value stored on disk and can be indexed, however it is still computed). It is intended to be changeable, and be the result of calculations on another column or columns.

A [DEFAULT Constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187872.aspx) simply inserts a default value into the column for any inserts, but then it is held as a  fixed value just like any other data column.

Comment: What is the difference in the calculated column and a non-nullable column as you listed?

Comment: @SmallFriesBigGuys A computed column like the one you created is always evaluated *at query time*. A default value is only generated *at insert time*.

Comment: @SmallFriesBigGuys as Aaron Bertrand said. I've expanded my answer a bit to include some information & links